# Octopus Deploy: Increment Variable

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am looking for a way to increment an integer value each time a deploy occurs.  I need this variable to stay updated so that when the script updates it for another deploy that it is incremented again.

I need the ability to ensure that port numbers for my services are not the same for each deploy.  i.e. Two services cannot listen on port 1122 and I need two services to be deployed.  My current solution is to do something like this:

```
int deployCounter = #{DeployCounter};
int port = #{DeployPort} + deployCounter;

Octopus.SetVariable("DeployPort", port.ToString());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whilst there are potential solutions, there's also potential problems (how will you manage a blacklist of ports as they are used by other applications). Can you explain why each new deployment has to be on a new port? Are these windows services in production and you have to maintain multiple versions? Do you only have to deal with the issue of two services on two different ports?

Comment: I am deploying brand new instances of my software internally for QA for each build.  That software is shipped with a windows service that is specifically bound to a port.  So if I am to get multiple versions of the software running on the same box I need to ensure that they are bound to different ports.  I don't need to worry about black listed ports and things like that because I also control the server.

Comment: I'd say that it's not a configuration issue but an additional step in deploy process that "selects a port" based on port availability check (for example via PowerShell) from some diapason or beginning from the configured value, whatever. This step then puts a "SelectedPort" variable in Octopus context and next steps would leverage this value.

Comment: That is exactly what I landed on except I am just assigning the port to 
major + minor + patch.
So 1.1.22 would be port 1122.
This is not 100%, but it is working for me for now.  I was just wondering what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: How many instances of these services need to run concurrently?

Comment: Honestly, that is up for debate.  Because we support multiple versions of our product in production I would say that we really need to potentially run ~200 concurrently.  Port range should not be a problem.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://octopus.com/blog/changing-website-port-on-each-deployment